# AngularJS $state open link in new tab using ctrl + click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to open a link in new tab just like a normal link would open when `ctrl + clicked`, except it has ui-sref directive attached to it which generate a href attribute with `/stateName?param1=test&param2=test`, due to which the tab is opened with URL: `domain.com/stateName?param1=test&param2=test`.

Now the issue is my app is loaded at

URL - `domain.com/SomePath#/`

and the generated link(ui-sref) is

URL - `domain.com/StateName?param1=test&param2=test`

Is there any way to provide base url to `ui-sref` when `ctrl + clicked`. I also want to preserve its normal behavior when clicking without ctrl pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work if you create a own function to handle this behavior. Here is a working [Fiddle in edit mode](http://jsfiddle.net/gwj84d24/6/) / [Fiddle preview mode](http://jsfiddle.net/gwj84d24/6/show/). This solution does provide the logic. Please create the URL you need on your own. Please note that fiddle is blocking `popups`.

#### View

```
<a ng-click="specialClick($event, 'stateName', { param: 'value'})">Click me</a>
```

#### AngularJS controller

```
$scope.specialClick = function (e, state, params) {
   if (e.ctrlKey) {
      window.open($state.href(state, params, '_blank'));
   } else {
      $state.go(state, params, {notify: false});
   }
}
```

Comment: How would you communicate target state? the desired URL is - domain.com/somePath#/<StateName>?param=1&param=2. Also, the element is already a link tag.

Comment: @utkarshsharma I'll improve my answer. While this target `domain.com/somePath#/<StateName>?param=1&param=2` is a custom URL the use of ui-sref is not important, right?

Comment: Only when the user tries to open it in new tab. Otherwise, it should preserve its behavior.

Comment: @utkarshsharma Updated =)

Comment: this seems to be neat solutions. Thanks.